# C++ detecting end of file

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program that is reading in info from a file, that stores info seperated by "$$$$". An example of how the file looks is:

`abc

bcd

$$$$

def

$$$$

qwe

gfh

$$$$`

How can I detect the file has ended, without using the eof() function?

I have it set like this,

`getline(sin,temp)

if (temp=="$$$$")

{

}`

After reading the last set of four dollars, how can I check the next line to ensure another set of data isn't beginning, and that the file has ended? If the file has indeed ended, I plan on using a boolean flag to terminate the while loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
while (getline(sin, temp))
{
    // use temp.
}
```

You will come out of loop once you are end of file.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you can't use `eof()` but you could get the file size first and then only read that many bytes.

Comment: its because of the architecture of my current program. I know I can redo it to make it better, but I don't have time for it right now, so I need to work with what I have.

Comment: @xbonez: I can't see why using eof() would require you to re-architect your program...

Comment: @xbonez can you please tell us exactly what architecture constraints you have that prohibit using `eof()` ?